# Why is Android Studio not populating a button id for me in Main Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I must be having a slow morning.  I started a new project to work with services.  I created a very simple layout with 2 buttons.  I should be able to go into my Main Activity and simply call "btnStartService" and implement an onlicklistener.  Android Studio will not populate the id for either button within the main activity.  What am I forgetting...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Service Stopped!"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStopService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnStartService"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStartService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="260dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
package com.dev20.servicepractice

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
        // This is where Android Studio cannot find the reference
        btnStartService

    }
}
```

I could do something like this, but it does not look as clean.  I used to be able to simply call the button without first initializing it with findbyviewid

```
        // This is where Android Studio cannot find the reference
        val btnStartService = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnStartService)
        btnStartService.setOnClickListener { 
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have this in your build.gradle? `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`

Comment: @DanielNugent you're the man.  That was it.  Going to get more coffee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have this in your app level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Then you should be able to import the layout in the activity:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

Answer (score 0):

In **build.gradle**, add below at the botton

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'